# How to import Python external files with Alexa Skill Kit SDK?

Tags: python, import, sdk, alexa-skills-kit

I just want to import a class (named Question) from a Python file (questionsServer.py) that is inside the same folder as the lambda function (Skill Code/lambda).

```
/Skill Code/
|__lambda
|____lambda_function.py
|____questionsServer.py
```

When I tried to do it the usual way using

```
from questionsServer import Question
```

It did not work. I have tried alternatives like:

```
from lambda.questionsServer import theClass
from .questionsServer import Question
from `questionsServer import Question`
```

But still doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to properly do this?

[screenshot of the folder, lambda function, and the class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAmpU.jpg)

Comment: If Python 3 then `from .filename import ClassName`   ..just a "." before file name as current directory for `Python 2` Make an empty file called `__init__.py` in the same directory as the files and then from `filename import classname`

Answer (score 0):

**Python 3**
then

```
from .filename import ClassName
```

..just a `.` before file name as it is in current directory

**Python 2**

Make an empty file called `__init__.py` in the same directory as the files and then from

```
`filename import classname`
```

Comment: It's working, I have made no changes, saved no files, did absolutely nothing but now it's working just fine. I have even compared my lines with the oldest version lines and nothing has changed at all it's just suddenly working.
It might be an issue due to Alexa Console and not the code. I will leave this question for future readers that might find themselves in this situation. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Imports behavior in python depends from where you launch your main script.
The best thing to do is to use relative import in your module packages so it works 100 % of times. To know your location just print `sys.path[0]`